# ECS task accessing S3 bucket website with Block Public Access enabled: "Access Denied"

Tags: permissions, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, policy, bucket

I have an ECS task configured to run an nginx container that I want to use as a reverse proxy to a S3 bucket website.

For security purposes, *Block public access* is turned on for the bucket so I am looking for a way to give Read access only to the ECS task.

I want my ECS task running an nginx reverse proxy to have `S3:GetObjects` access to my website bucket. The bucket cannot be public so I want to restrict it to the ecs task using the ecs task IAM role as Principal.

IAM role:
*arn:aws:iam:::role/* was configured with an attached policy that allows all S3 actions in the bucket and its objects:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "S3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In Trusted Entities, I added permission to assume the ECS Task role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that the EC2 target group health check is always returning Access Denied to the bucket and its objects.
`[08/Jun/2020:20:33:19 +0000] “GET / HTTP/1.1” 403 303 “-“ “ELB-HealthChecker/2.0”`

I also tried to give it permission to by adding the bucket policy below, but I believe it is not needed as the IAM role already have access to it…

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allowNginxProxy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried using `”AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:role/<ECS_TASK_ROLE>"` as Principal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Side-note:** It is generally not a good idea to assign `s3:*` permissions. This includes the ability to do _anything_ to the bucket, including deleting the bucket and all contents within the bucket. Try to limit permissions to only those needed by the application (eg `GetObject`).

Comment: The "EC2 target group health check" is coming from the Load Balancer, correct? And it is pointing to a path on nginx? If you manually go to that path, does it return a 200 response? Does your Reserve Proxy work (aside from the health check)? If not, what can you see in the logs?

Comment: The whole solution involves Route53 hosted zone pointing to the application load balancer listening 443 from the ecs target group that has a healthy instance running the nginx container. 

Now back to S3, if we disabled *Block Public Access* option for existing ACLs, a HTTP 200 response is returned and I can access the website index.html.

Comment: Why are you running a health check on S3? I could understand running it on the load balancer that points to ECS, but there's really no need for it on S3.

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility here:

1. Check if your S3 Objects are encrypted? If yes, your ECS Task Role should also have the permission to perform decryption. Otherwise, you would also get permission denied exception. One example can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decrypt-kms-encrypted-objects-s3/).

Answer (score 0):

The EC2 instances probably don't have an instance profile configured.

1. Create an EC2 role 'ecsInstanceRole' with the below trusted relationship.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Use this managed policy `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`
3. Create an instance profile

Reference to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html).